# Ruby (rails) constructor call giving syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, constructor, syntax-error

I'm learning Rails development with the book "Agile Web Development With Rails" by Sam Ruby and I'm getting a syntax error when I invoke a model's constructor. I have found two ways to invoke the constructor using alternate syntax, but I'd really like to know why the syntax that is used in the book is not working in my development environment.

The book uses syntax where the key/value pairs are surrounded by parentheses similar to this:

```
product = Product.new (title: "foo", description: "yyy")
```

This code is in a unit test. When I run 'rake test:units', I get the following error:

```
product = Product.new (title: "foo", description: "yyy")
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__^

ruby_book_demo/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL

Note, I've been able to get arround the syntax error by doing:

```
product = Product.new title: "foo", description: "yyy" #WORKS
```

or

```
product = Product.new ({title: "foo", description: "yyy"}) # WORKS!
```

but I'd really like to know why I got the error. I'm using jruby:

jruby -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a space between Product.new and the parentheses:

```
Product.new(title: 'foo', description: 'bar')
```

The reason it works without the parentheses is because they are optional and require a space in that case.

Comment: It looks like it works w/out parentheses when you use curly brackets, but I don't recommend doing this. Either don't use parentheses or don't use a space.

Comment: Thanks. It strikes me as horrible that the syntax is that rigid, but oh well.

Comment: I suspect it is because the parens can also mean a grouped expression, as in `(1+3)`.   With the space there it assumes it is a perens-less call, and then the contents should be an expression, not a param list.